# Trouble with FQL stream_tag

Tags: facebook, api

I am trying to retrive posts from a users news feed in which my fan page has been tagged. I'm seaching through stream_tag with FQL but zero results are returned.

- Posted a comment on my wall in which I tagged a friend, myself, and my fan page.
- Used the Graph API Explorer - developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
- Used the explorer as one of my apps, and granted every type of permission.

Did the following query:
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT post_id,actor_id FROM stream_tag WHERE target_id = [fan page id]

The following is returned: data: []

This seems to indicate that there is no resaults but I know the tag exists. When I do a query with target_id=me() results are returned, but according to the documentation the target_id can also be a fan page( http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_tag/ to craft the query). 
How can I create a query that returns posts my fan page is tagged in?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the exact same thing when I came across your post.  It looks like there currently is a [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/292463424186102/) open that the stream_tag table does not work with when the target is a page.